# В шахматах: жертвовать фигуру или фигурой?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как я понимаю, фигуру в шахматах не дарят (см. словарь, п. 1), а "губят ради чего-нибудь" (см. п. 2), то есть надо бы говорить "жертвовать фугурой". Однако шахматисты говорят "жертвовать фигуру". А вот фильм назвали "Жертвуя пешкой" (фильм об американском гроссмейстере Бобби Фишере). И журналисты пишут "жертвовать пешкой".  Как это понять?

Примеры:

создалась очень сложная позиция, в которой я собирался пожертвовать **коня** ([Каспаров](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=HXXIBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT53&lpg=PT53&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80&source=bl&ots=YaJRKXwdAt&sig=2amJ6aP34Y3TBKfg17rYDZssqGI&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7hfzTje_UAhVjCZoKHUY4APY4HhDoAQhGMAU#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80&f=false))

Белым выгодно временно пожертвовать **коня** ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B)))

гроссмейстер жертвовал **пешки**, тяжелые и легкие **фигуры** направо и налево
([Ильф и Петров](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=LTnsApEb21MC&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80&source=bl&ots=Sy13tMoRVb&sig=5u5fuFdrCJhmoxroR2Gq3pFIQbs&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQuNS1ie_UAhVEKpoKHbXQCR4Q6AEIVTAH#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80&f=false))

Но (из Нац. корпуса):

Чтобы избежать катастрофической «вилки», жертвую **пешкой** [Юлия Вишневецкая. Почему Россия — не Москва // «Русский репортер», № 43 (122), 12-19 ноября 2009, 2009]

Максим Ноткин. Не жертвуя **качеством** (2004) // «64 — Шахматное обозрение», 2004.06.15

Для справки. Словарь Ушакова:

ЖЕ́РТВОВАТЬ, жертвую, жертвуешь, несовер. (к пожертвовать).

1. что и без доп. Приносить в дар, делать вклады куда-нибудь; дарить, давать (книжн.). Купцы много жертвовали на монастыри. Жертвовать в пользу бедных.

|| Давать, дарить (разг. ирон.). Жертвую тебе полтинник.

2. кем-чем. Не щадить кого-нибудь, подвергать гибельной опасности, губить ради чего-нибудь. Не могу жертвовать своим ребенком. Жертвовать собой. Жертвовать жизнью.

|| чем. Отказываться от чего-нибудь, пренебрегать чем-нибудь ради чего-нибудь другого. «Она жертвовала своею страстью к нарядам для отца.» Л.Толстой. Усовершенствовать прибор, не жертвуя его чувствительностью.

Comment: В шахматах жертвуют качеств**о** (разницу между ценностью ладьи и лёгкой фигуры), а не качеством. Это как пожертвовать деньги на что-то, с той разницей, что в шахматах это делают с расчётом. Заголовок мог быть намеренно сделан двусмысленным (второй смысл - "качество игры"). "Жертвуя пешкой" - могло быть результатом редактуры в непрофильном журнале (жертвуют всегда пешк**у**). Говорю как кандидат в мастера :) .

Comment: Ну, чё, скажу и я... Это традиционная грамматическая форма - "жертвовать фигуру". Так сложилось исторически. Не ссорьтесь, дети.

Answer (score 2):

Скажу как кандидат в мастера спорта по шахматам, пожертвовавший за свою жизнь не один набор шахматных фигур. Жертвуют **чем-то**, но проблема в том, что после того как ты предложил в жертву **что-то** противник может быть эту жертву не принять. Поэтому, для победы я могу **жертвовать ладью**, а если соперник жертву примет, то я выиграю **жертвой ладьи**.

Comment: Объяснение не очень подходит. Вот в шашках нельзя не принять жертву, и всё-таки шашисты жертвуют шашку, а не шашкой.

Answer (score 1):

Скажу и я как кандидат в мастера, а то что ж... В шахматах всегда жертвуют что-то, а не чем-то. Не только фигуру, но и темп, бывает, жертвуют.
Не случайно примеры из нацкорпуса: "жертвую пешкой", "жертвуя качеством" и т.п. принадлежат не шахматистам.

Comment: В ответе — рекомендоваться... Не слабо!

Comment: Вы только подтвердили то, что сказано в вопросе. Но интересно знать почему так, с лингвистической точки зрения.

Comment: @М_Г, вы же сами привели статью из словаря. Там уж так все понятно. "Не щадить", "подвергать гибельной опасности",  "губить" и т.п. – это всё не о шахматах.

Comment: Однако п.1 (принисить в дар) тоже не подходит. Поэтому мне кажется п.2 более подходящим. Единственное мнение, на мой взгляд заслуживающее внимание (хотя и спорное), высказывалось @МаркИз: жертвовать в шахматах - это предлагать жертву, то есть все-таки как бы дарить (п.1)

Comment: "Жертвовать кем-чем" используется, когда говорят об отвлеченных понятиях (не предметах): жертвовать репутацией, красотой, здоровьем, жизнью и т.п., либо о живом существе: не могу жертвовать ребенком.

Answer (score 1):

Да, "Жертвовать что" и "жертвовать чем" имеют несколько разную стилистическую (и даже смысловую) окраску, но в шахматах больше подходит вариант "что". Марк Из прав по сути, хотя неверно это объясняет. Дело не в том, можно ли принять жертву или не принять. "Жертвовать чем" - это вопрос качественный. *"Пожертвовала фигурой ради возможности съесть второй десерт"* и *"пожертвовать фигуру ради получения позиционного преимущества"*.  Оцените разницу. В первом случае жертва - некая условность, перед выбором одного или другого, по сути это не жертва даже, а выбор из двух зайцев того, что пожирнее. А второе - сознательный отказ от чего-то ценного ради получения дальнейших выгод.

Поэтому  в шахматах - жертвовать фигуру, пешку, качество, темп.

> то я выиграю жертвой ладьи.

А тут просто другой случай управления. К гагольному управлению отношения не имеет.